# Thermocouple Op-Amp - Arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, thermocouple

First of all, I know that this is not the best way to do this, even more so because I am using the LM358. I don t want extraordinary results.

Now, on the matter of the problem. I have attached the circuit. The only difference is that I mounted the 100nF Capacitor right at the input+ and GND of the op-amp.

The problem is that I get nothing as a result and if I remove the CAP I get a reading, but only for a few miliseconds, then it goes back to zero. What can I do?

[image]

The code is basically this, where the show() function is a function to display the number on an three digit led segment display.

```
 Input = analogRead(0);
 Input = map(Input, 0, 450, 25, 350);
 show(Input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a 50:50 chance of having an op-amp with a negative Vos, so it might have to get fairly hot before you see a change, but a soldering iron is hotter than that.

I suspect you may have connected the thermocouple backwards (red is typically minus in north America), in which case the op-amp would remain saturated at the lower rail.

To avoid the first problem, connect the minus side of the thermocouple to a voltage divider that gives you a couple of mV. Something like 10 ohms/20K to +5.

Comment: I couldn't have connected the thermocouple backwards because I use a soldering iron with a connector, and the minus is connected to the main ground and the other wire to the non inverting input.

Comment: I will try to use the offset voltage method, but as a last resort. I have a PCB already done and mounted in a 3D printed case, it will be very tricky to install it.

Comment: Well, did you measure the input voltage at the non-inverting input? Even on a 200mV range, which most cheap meters have, you should be able to tell what is going on. I would say that 10K is too high for good accuracy, but that isn't going to happen anyway.

Comment: I think I'll just try to find an OP27 for starters, if I don't, I'll start to measure all the voltages and start from there. And thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Umm... an OP27 will actually be worse than an LM358 in that circuit.

Comment: Doesn't the very low Vos make it better?

Comment: Not a chance of it working at all- the input common mode range, output swing and minimum supply voltage are all inadequate.

Comment: P.S. It's also a different pinout, if that matters, being a single vs. a dual.

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot the the LM358 is dual. Anyway, I did some measurements and I get really weird results. With the pin floating (the + side of thermocouple not connected) i get about 10-20mV at the input of the op-amp. When I connect the thermocouple, i get about -30mV at the non inverting input. If i just measure the thermocouple unconnected, i get about 10mV which is correct.

Comment: I just check this circuit apart from all the schematic and it works fine. Is it possible that a SMPS introduces noise into the op-amp? I have the output of the SMPS regulated via a LM7805, but the ground is connected also to the mains ground.

Comment: Certainly possible - reasonable care is necessary with smps grounds

Comment: I just tested the circuit with and without the MCU (ATMEGA8). It works when I remove the ATMEGA8. I even cut off the trace between op-amp output and ADC pin and i still get a -30mV noise.

Comment: Well, you certainly have (comparatively) enormous currents flowing through the ground pin on the MCU if you are driving LED displays, some reasonable care is necessary with the way those currents flow.

Comment: I think I have just found the problem. The circuit works fine if I remove the MCU. I think the problem is that the output is PWM and that is introducing noise. Any Ideas how to remove this? Would just adding a 100nF capacitor to the op-amp supply solve the problem?

Comment: Probably not, it's probably bad layout.

Comment: Do you mean that the op-amp is too close to the PWM output?

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood how a thermocouple works. Where you connect the thermocouple to the printed circuit board has a specific temperature, let's call it 20C. Then the thermocouple will have an output referenced to that temperature. If the thermocouple is at the same temperarature as the reference point, the thermocouple output will be 0. With a K type, the voltage difference will be about 41 uV/deg C, or about 5 mV/deg C. Try your setup with the thermocouple at some much higher temperature, like putting it in boiling water.

In addition, your op amp is a very bad choice. The LM358 has a worst-case offset voltage of 5 mV, and the op amp has no way to distinguish this from the thermocouple voltage. So, in the worst case, your thermometer could need 122 C at the thermocouple (122 x 41 uV = 5.002 mV) before its output gets off zero.

Comment: Maybe I explaine myself wrong. The test is done with a soldering iron and its included thermocouple and it is on and I keep the testing until it reaches about 200 - 220 (the temperature i can melt solder). In this time the output is still 0 (on display I get 25 degrees because of the map function). Even with the poor LM358 I should still get a reading at 200 degrees celsius).

Comment: Also, if I disconnect the thermocouple, and let the ADC pin floating, I do get a result from noise maybe like 600.

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe the soldering iron test ("I keep the testing until it reaches about 200 - 220") and the equalising reading make me suspect you are not getting a good differential reading. NB: it depends greatly on the thermocouple used. You didn't specify but I'm assuming a Type K probe.

If the cold junction is not thermally stabilised, it is possible both ends are being allowed to warm up and any differential is being lost. Safety prevents me from suggesting you just stick your finger on the supposedly cold junction!

I can confirm that it is possible to get a "decent" reading from a Type K using an LM358 at temperatures above 200C - because I coincidentally tried exactly this recently, and you can see all my notes [on GitHub here](https://github.com/tardate/LittleArduinoProjects/tree/master/playground/TemperatureLoggerTypeK).

To isolate the problem I would suggest:

- leave the capacitor out until you have a circuit that works. It's just there to stabilise the reading.
- make sure it's not simply a backwards thermocouple as Spehro suggested
- the circuit doesn't explicitly show the -ve of the thermocouple grounded. Check that it is.
- test the op-amp circuit with a voltage input in place of the thermocouple to make sure you are getting the expected gain for a predicted Seebeck voltage
- if you have an oscilloscope or µV-capable meter, use it to test the thermocouple (on its own). You should be able to see the voltage differential when you repeat the heating test

Note two differences in the circuit I used:

- there is no R5. With an "ideal" OpAmp it should make no difference, but it may be soaking up precious µV depending how good your particular LM358 is
- gain is 3x higher

Comment: I did some measurements and I get really weird results. With the pin floating (the + side of thermocouple not connected) I get about 10-20mV at the input of the op-amp. When I connect the thermocouple, i get about -30mV at the non inverting input. If i just measure the thermocouple unconnected, i get about 10mV which is correct.

Comment: floating inputs are ... floating, so don't mean much;-) Remember the op amp will attempt to equalise the inputs by adjusting the output (only). Try measuring the output. I just wired up an LM358P with 10mV on + and the 120k/1k non-inverting amp config. Theory says 1.21V on the output. I measure 1.10V. If you can't reproduce that, something's up with your op amp or wiring. Beyond that, I just have wild guesses sorry. It might help if you clarify how you are connecting both ends of the thermocouple, and exactly what model it is.

Comment: I think I have just found the problem. The circuit works fine if I remove the MCU. I think the problem is that the output is PWM and that is introducing noise. Any Ideas how to remove this? Would just adding a 100nF capacitor to the op-amp supply solve the problem?